# Spyder 4: up/down arrows in IPython console (scroll for program input)

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I upgraded to Spyder 4.2.0 in December (2020). Previously I used Spyder 3.x. I run my code from the editor in the IPython console. They are simple programs that prompt for console input. It is similar to running from the command line (`python program.py args`).

When I am testing, I frequently use different combinations of the same input (user names for example). With Spyder 3.x I could scroll back thru previous inputs with the up/down arrows while running the program to reuse a previously entered value. I can't figure out how to get the same behavior with Spyder 4. An example is shown in the code block below.

```
runfile('E:/walker/optimization/test_prog.py', args='../large', wdir='E:/walker/optimization')
Loading data...Data loaded.
Input Name1: [I input the 1st name]
Input Name2: [I input the 2nd name]
Some printed output here...

Now the program prompts for new input...
Input Name1: [I want to reenter name2 above by going back with the up arrow]
Input Name2: [I want to reenter name1 above by going back with the up arrow]
```

I can't figure out how to do this with Spyder 4.x. I suspect something changed with the upgrade from Spyder 3. I've looked at the settings for **IPython** and **Run** in **Tools/Preferences**. No mention of arrows or scrolling input.
Note: Scrolling in the console works fine when I am coding in the console and want to retrieve a previous Python command. This question is specific to program input while running code from the editor.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The way we handle `input` in Spyder 4 changed significantly with respect to Spyder 3. Furthermore, given that we'd need a significant time investment to support this use case and the gain is very little, I don't think we'll restore that functionality back, sorry.

Comment: @Carlos Cordoba, thanks for the explanation -- at least I'm not missing something. Sorry to hear it won't be implemented. I'm surprised it's difficult. I can retrieve previous inputs in a Windows Command Prompt window (after entering `python prog.py`). Again, thanks.

Comment: The problem is our IPython console is not a real system terminal (like `cmd.exe` or `xterm`) nor it uses terminal technologies to work. Instead, it's a graphical application that emulates the look and feel of a terminal. So, to support this use case in Spyder 4+ we'd need to add a history of commands to `input` (separate from IPython and IPdb histories) and retrieve it with the up and down arrows. That's why I said it'd be too much work for too little gain (you're the first person I've heard who needs it).

Comment: Interesting. No worries. I use this when I'm running simple test cases and need to test slightly different inputs. I got spoiled with Spyder 3. :-) Now I just run these tests in the command window.